# Passing state to function pointer

Tags: c++

I am using a function in an external library that has this type:

```
int libraryFunction(int* fp(int))
```

However, I need the callback to also be passed an `ostream`, and the library function does not have any overloads that allow functors, lambdas, or passing extra arguments. Is there a way to get the `ostream` into the callback?

Comment: is this real C++ library, or only C with some elements. I expected object functor instead C function pointer

Comment: It's a C++ library, it's just a really old one.

Comment: Can you choose the `int` parameter or is it used by the library?

Comment: The parameter is used by the library, so I can't control what is passed to it.

Comment: I don't see a way unless you use `static` members and functions within a class, or old-school global variables.

Comment: Do you need different ostreams for different callbacks?  Will you only need one callback at a time?  If so, you can use a global variable to hold the ostream.  Otherwise, I can't really think of a good way to do this with this signature.

Comment: For my specific case, I guess I could just use a global variable. I don't like this library very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library API does not support function object or passing a custom state pointer, then you will have to store the state of your object (here an `ostream`) on your side.

The function being stateless, there is no other choice than storing the state or a pointer to the state at a compile time known location.

The pitfall with this is that you have to ensure the lifetime of the state matches the lifetime of the callback in the library. The `ostream` must not be destroyed to early.

Another problem with this is that unless you can pass some kind of index to your function, you will have to declare a separate function for each state you need.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the int, and use it to look up everything your callback needs. If it's only an ostream...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
int main() {
    enum {
         jkout = 0,
         cout = 1
    };
    std::map<int, std::ostream*> lookup;
    std::ofstream jout("junk.txt");
    lookup[jkout] = &jout;
    lookup[cout] = &std::cout;
    *(lookup[jkout]) << "hello\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a fleeting moment, I had that plus-one feeling. Then a drive-by clicker.